# hide/show column on conditionally in datatable AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

I'm show the user list using datatable angularjs. I want to hide show column using conditionally.suppose role is onther then last column is not show and role is admin then show this last column.how can do that I don't know any one know how can do that please let me know.

#### This is my controller.js:

```
app.controller("userscontroller", ["$scope", "$http", "DTOptionsBuilder", "DTColumnBuilder", "userservice","$compile"
 function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder,userservic,$compile) {       
$scope.dtColumns = [            
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("fullName", "Full Name").withOption('name', 'firstname'),
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("username", "Name").withOption('name',     'username'),
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("email", "Email").withOption('name', 'email'), 
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Action').notSortable()
    .renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {            
            return '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="delete(' + data.id + ');"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>' + '</button>';                    
    })          
]

$scope.dtOptions = userservice.GetAllUser(DTOptionsBuilder)
.withOption('processing', true)
.withOption('serverSide', true)
.withPaginationType('full_numbers')
.withDisplayLength(50)
.withOption('aaSorting', [3, 'desc'])

 function createdRow(row, data, dataIndex) {
$compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
 } }]);
```

Here I want to if(IsAdmin) then show delete column other wise hide this column how can do?

Comment: @lin can you know please how can do that?

Comment: Can you use an `if` statement when you define $scope.dtColumns to exclude the column you want to hide when the isAdmin is false?

Comment: sry what you want to say i can't understand can you please give me answr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if(user.configName == 'Admin') 
{
    vm.dtColumnDefs = [
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).notSortable()
        ];
}
else {
vm.dtColumnDefs = [
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notVisible(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).notSortable()
        ];
}
```

In the above code notVisible() method is used to hide the second column in table. Using this, you can make columns visible and hidden for particular user role.

Comment: but how can check condition? on this wave

Comment: i want to check the cond on this whole coumn on action so if you know please edit your answer please

Comment: can you any other way for this i don't repeated this type code in js. need reduce code so any other way for that then please let me know

Comment: you can try using ternary operator within dtColumnDefs for column 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
if(user.configName == 'Admin'){
               return '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="delete(' + data.id + ');"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>' + '</button>';
            }
```

Comment: but with your solution just hide button not a hide column i want to hide whole column any idea